# why my calendar in vuetify is look like this ?? (disorder) on top right

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

why my calendar is look like this ??

this is my code for calendar component

calendar.vue

```
<template>
    <v-row class="fill-height">
        <v-col>
            <v-sheet height="64">
                <v-toolbar
                        flat
                >
                    <v-btn
                            outlined
                            class="mr-4"
                            color="grey darken-2"
                            @click="setToday"
                    >
                        Today
                    </v-btn>
                    <v-btn
                            fab
                            text
                            small
                            color="grey darken-2"
                            @click="prev"
                    >
                        <v-icon small>
                            mdi-chevron-left
                        </v-icon>
                    </v-btn>
                    <v-btn
                            fab
                            text
                            small
                            color="grey darken-2"
                            @click="next"
                    >
                        <v-icon small>
                            mdi-chevron-right
                        </v-icon>
                    </v-btn>
                    <v-toolbar-title v-if="$refs.calendar">
                        {{ $refs.calendar.title }}
                    </v-toolbar-title>
                    <v-spacer></v-spacer>
                    <v-menu
                            bottom
                            right
                    >
                        <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
                            <v-btn
                                    outlined
                                    color="grey darken-2"
                                    v-bind="attrs"
                                    v-on="on"
                            >
                                <span>{{ typeToLabel[type] }}</span>
                                <v-icon right>
                                    mdi-menu-down
                                </v-icon>
                            </v-btn>
                        </template>
                        <v-list>
                            <v-list-item @click="type = 'day'">
                                <v-list-item-title>Day</v-list-item-title>
                            </v-list-item>
                            <v-list-item @click="type = 'week'">
                                <v-list-item-title>Week</v-list-item-title>
                            </v-list-item>
                            <v-list-item @click="type = 'month'">
                                <v-list-item-title>Month</v-list-item-title>
                            </v-list-item>
                            <v-list-item @click="type = '4day'">
                                <v-list-item-title>4 days</v-list-item-title>
                            </v-list-item>
                        </v-list>
                    </v-menu>
                </v-toolbar>
            </v-sheet>
            <v-sheet height="600">
                <v-calendar
                        ref="calendar"
                        v-model="focus"
                        color="primary"
                        :events="events"
                        :event-color="getEventColor"
                        :type="type"
                        @click:event="showEvent"
                        @click:more="viewDay"
                        @click:date="viewDay"
                        @change="updateRange"
                ></v-calendar>
                <v-menu
                        v-model="selectedOpen"
                        :close-on-content-click="false"
                        :activator="selectedElement"
                        offset-x
                >
                    <v-card
                            color="grey lighten-4"
                            min-width="350px"
                            flat
                    >
                        <v-toolbar
                                :color="selectedEvent.color"
                                dark
                        >
                            <v-btn icon>
                                <v-icon>mdi-pencil</v-icon>
                            </v-btn>
                            <v-toolbar-title v-html="selectedEvent.name"></v-toolbar-title>
                            <v-spacer></v-spacer>
                            <v-btn icon>
                                <v-icon>mdi-heart</v-icon>
                            </v-btn>
                            <v-btn icon>
                                <v-icon>mdi-dots-vertical</v-icon>
                            </v-btn>
                        </v-toolbar>
                        <v-card-text>
                            <span v-html="selectedEvent.details"></span>
                        </v-card-text>
                        <v-card-actions>
                            <v-btn
                                    text
                                    color="secondary"
                                    @click="selectedOpen = false"
                            >
                                Cancel
                            </v-btn>
                        </v-card-actions>
                    </v-card>
                </v-menu>
            </v-sheet>
        </v-col>
    </v-row>
</template>
```

and the script part look like reference
exactly what is in reference  https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/calendars/#click but is look like this [image]

i want to be look like the reference
this picture is correct one: [image]
the problem is for that i am use rtl in presets
whta should i do ?
i want to use rtl and don't want that disorder on top right